# How to set a bitmap as icon into button, in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

I try to set icon into myButton, it works! (see the code below).

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha, 0, 0, 0);
```

And now, I downloaded an image from a URL, bitmap.

My question is how to set myButton's icon by replace `R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha` to `bitmap`.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Place your image in your drawable folder. Name it properly (respecting the rules for valid characters). Load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's work!!!

```
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mybitmap);
myButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(bd,null,null,null);
```

Thank you, Rishad Appat, rekire and everybody.
I can do it.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create bitmap drawable from bitmap..

```
BitmapDrawable bdrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),bitmap);
```

Then set to button like this...

```
Button btn = (Button) fndViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(bdrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TextView.setCompoundDrawables(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) method, this requires a `Drawable` so you need to wrap your bitmap with a `BitmapDrawable`.

This should work:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), yourBitmap);
yourButton.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
```

If this is not correctly displayed, then you need to fix the bounds yourself with this call:

```
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, yourBitmap.getWidth(), yourBitmap.getHeight());
```